# Shared stated V Messaging

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing

There are two architectural solutions to achieve concurrency:

- Mulitple thread which shared state. This needs locks of blocking of code etc
- Messaging model. Messages get put onto queues and then are processed by a single thread.

My question is, when does multiple threads outperform the messaging model? For example, say you have a single server which can process message requests asynchronously by putting them on an internal cue. IS there any bottle neck introduced (for example even at TCP / IP) level that is not introduced if you use a multi threaded server model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although answers to your question can depend on a lot of factors, I think an important aspect to consider is how to take best advantage of multiple CPUs in your machine. As you describe it here, the message queue approach with one thread handling all messages is not optimal if your machine has multiple CPUs. The one thread handling all messages might max out one CPU, whereas other threads will under-use the other available CPUs. The shared state approach could potentially take better advantage of multiple CPUs.

However, another approach is to modify the message queue algorithm by having multiple threads -- up to one or two below the number of CPUs -- emptying the queue and processing the messages concurrently. This gives you quite some control over how CPUs get utilized, especially if you have the option to bind particular threads to particular CPUs. This high degree of control might make the multi-threaded version of the message queue approach preferable over the shared state.

The assumption that this answer is relevant, stems from the fact that many machines nowadays do have multiple CPUs. If this does not apply to your situation, then please give a more detailed description of your boundary conditions, and what you mean by performance when you say "outperform".